Eloquent Sluggable getting wrong record and not scoping based on route parameters
I have one route like this: /vehicles/vehicle-one/projects/project-one
And another route like this: /vehicles/vehicle-two/projects/project-one
I am using the Eloquent Sluggable package to handle the slugs for things like the  Vehicle and Project models. For the Project model i also have this that makes slugs unique only within the scope of vehicles:
public function scopeWithUniqueSlugConstraints(Builder $query, Model $model, $attribute, $config, $slug)
{
    $vehicle = $model->vehicle;

    return $vehicle ? $query->where('vehicle_id', $vehicle->getKey()) : null;


This works fine with creating the project model records. However, given the URLs above, this one /vehicles/vehicle-two/projects/project-one is pulling up the information from vehicle one. It seems like it is just running Project::where('slug', $project->slug) and finding the first one regardless of the vehicle scope.
For now, i can brute force it in my controller by doing something like this:
$project = Project::where('vehicle_id', $vehicle->id)->where('slug', $project->slug)->first();

Is there a way i can handle this in the RouteServiceProvider.php file instead? I'd rather the controller actually receive the right model to begin with.
UPDATE:
When using this URL: /vehicles/vehicle-two/projects/project-one
Here is the route definition:
Route::prefix('vehicles')->name('vehicles.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{vehicle}/projects/{project}', [ProjectController::class, 'show'])->name('projects.show');
});

Here is the ProjectController method as well:
public function show(Vehicle $vehicle, Project $project)
{
    // $project is holding the Project with the slug `project-one` from Vehicle One instead of Vehicle Two
}


You have to show us the route definition...

@matiaslauriti my fault, i have added that to the post.
